# Is Denormalization good for performance

Tags: sql, denormalization

First of all sorry for my English.

I am working on a database which contain about a million of records. There are like 10 tables and all of them are connected using foreign keys. So let suppose the entity for which I am saving records is person. So in 1 table I have person details in other table I have his job information etc. I meant to say that my database is very much normalize right now. To fetch the data I am running queries that contain several joins and I am getting data in normal time. However I have seen on some forums/tech blogs that if we just want to SELECT the data then a denormalized database can increase performance dramatically. I have tried doing it with my own database and I made a column "denormal_data". While working with it I realize that my table is getting a bit bigger and right now it contain more then 50 columns. Is it good ? Do I really need a denormalized database table ? Is it a good practice?

Well its most likely to be a general discussion then any kind of issue and only for learning purpose. Any kind of expert advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Occasionally it can help, but it's very dependent on your specific scenario. Can you give more detail about your tables and joins?

Answer (score 4):

I read on the Internet that taking certain pills can improve my chances with the ladies, but I don't believe everything I read.  Neither should you.

Normalization is a good thing - don't throw it away until you've exhausted all other avenues for better performance.

All your tables should have primary keys.

All your foreign keys should have indexes; so should all columns in WHERE clauses.

A million records isn't a large database these days, unless you're using something like Access that was intended for single user desktop applications.

You should EXPLAIN PLAN on all your queries to see how they're performing.

I would not change anything without getting some meaningful data first.  Unless you have a good baseline, you won't know if you really have a problem OR if the cure is effective.

Comment: +1 as I was going to say the same thing. I would also add that a good database design keeps data together when it is related and apart when it isn't. If you have a business concept of a "Customer" but need to perform a flat join across several tables to get the basic "Customer" record out of the database, you should consider combining the data.

Comment: +1 Who was it who said that "**premature** optimisation is the root of all evil"?

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is usefull to denormalize when there are a lot of data to compute. For example in forum we use a column called "message_number" or "topic_length" to avoid the function "count" that can be really greedy in performance.

I think there is a lot of way to increase performance of a data base by denormalisation, but you have to becareful.

Answer (score 0):

Denormalization is a strategy available to you when you need it. When you need it is when the database performance is negatively affecting your application **AND** you've already tried all of the easier tricks (indexes, etc). Denormalizing is not free. You have to do things by hand which you would otherwise not have to (e.g. you want to update the user's email address? do it in all 5 tables where it shows up).

tl;dr: Use it only when you need it. You probably don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to use denormaliation, create a second set of tables that get synchronized regularely, which contain the data you want to have fast access to in a denormalized format. it's going to be stale data (but isn't it going to be right after the refresh?), and you should indicate how old it is.

you may also want to look at the term [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)